Get URL of current webpage using AppleScript in Safari doesn't work
I'm create Quick Action (QA) in Automator:

Select no input in any application, check Output replaces selected text.
Add a simple AppleScript:
on run {input, parameters}
 tell application "Safari" to set myURL to URL of current tab of front window
 return myURL
end run


Save.

Then:
If I click Run - I can see URL in Results (obviously Safari must be open in background).
If I Ctrl + Click on any text field on any web page in Safari and call my QA - I get an error: "AppleEvent timed out".
If I call my QA in TextEdit - URL is inserted fine.
Also tried this code, but it didn't help:
on run {input, parameters}
    delay 1
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        set currentTab to current tab of front window
        set myURL to URL of currentTab
    end tell
    return myURL
end run

Is there any way to resolve this problem?

It works the same way with other apps, for example creating a Quick Action that scripts TextEdit to return its document name, and trying to use it in TextEdit.  Looking at the ScriptMonitor.app status item (the gear in the menu bar), the workflow is hanging in the Run AppleScript action, so it may just be a result of the way that accessing the text field with control-click and the Quick Action are both targeting the same application.

Ok, so there's no way I can get the URL of the active tab in Safari using Quick Action, thanks. I guess I'll have to do it through an extension.
